# Error in Visual Studio Code 2019 (C++) saying "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, eigen

I am getting an error in Visual Studio 2019 in my C++ program. I have a function prototype defined in a header file called "Header.h" with a return type of class myMatrix. I have the function definition in a file called "Fuctions.cpp". My problem is that I get a compile error stating "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone". However, the return type is the exact same in both the function prototype as well as in the function definition. Below are my complete "Header.h" and "Functions.cpp" files in case my mistake lies elsewhere in my code. I tried looking for hours for similar problems to mine here in stack overflow but I could not find any relevant answers. I also copied the function prototype and pasted that at the top of my function definition, so I know that it's not a silly typo that's causing the problem. I looked at potential problems like missing semicolons and stuff like that and I could not find the source of the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Header.h file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace Eigen;

// utilities
bool is_number(const std::string& str);
unsigned int countWords(const std::string& str);


// functions for reading data in
void readGeneral(const std::string& filename, std::vector<std::string>& vec);
myMatrix read2Mat(const std::string& filename, unsigned int mode);


// class used to be able to store strings alongside doubles in a quasi-matrix data structure
class myMatrix {
// values stores the values, while ids0 and ids1 give us the possibility to store any string id columns
// NOTE: vectors "ids0" and "ids1" are not mandatory
private:
    MatrixXd values;
    std::vector<std::string> ids0, ids1;
public:
    // class constructor
    // if no third parameter is passed, only values is given a size
    // if third parameter is 1, values and ids0 are given a size
    // if third parameter is 2, values; ids0; and ids1 are given a size
    myMatrix(const unsigned int& n, const unsigned int& m, unsigned int mode = 0) {
        if (mode == 0) {
            values.resize(n, m);
        }
        else if (mode == 1) {
            values.resize(n, m);
            ids0.resize(n);
        }
        else if (mode == 2) {
            values.resize(n, m);
            ids0.resize(n);
            ids1.resize(n);
        }
    }

    // copy constructor (shallow copy of class)
    // could make it a deep copy but unnecessary because my class values are not pointers
    myMatrix(const myMatrix& other)
        : values(other.values), ids0(other.ids0), ids1(other.ids1)
    {

    }

    // allows access to the values inside "MatrixXd values" by simply using the parenthesis operator
    double& operator()(const unsigned int& row, const unsigned int& col); // for normal objects
    double operator()(const unsigned int& row, const unsigned int& col) const; // for const objects

    // allows access to the string vector id0
    std::string& ref0(const unsigned int& i) {
        return ids0[i];
    }
    std::string ref0(const unsigned int& i) const{
        return ids0[i];
    }
    // allows access to the string vector id1
    std::string& ref1(const unsigned int& i) {
        return ids0[i];
    }
    std::string ref1(const unsigned int& i) const{
        return ids0[i];
    }

    // member function that prints out the existing variables within the class
    void print() {
        if (ids0.empty()) {
            std::cout << "myMatrix values: " << std::endl << values << "\n\n";
        }
        else if (ids1.empty()) {
            std::cout << "myMatrix values: " << std::endl << values << "\n\n";
            for (auto& str : ids0)
                std::cout << "myMatrix idos0: " << str << " ";
            std::cout << "\n\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "myMatrix values: " << std::endl << values << "\n\n";
            for (auto& str : ids0)
                std::cout << "myMatrix idos0: " << str << " ";
            std::cout << "\n\n";
            for (auto& str : ids1)
                std::cout << "myMatrix idos1: " << str << " ";
            std::cout << "\n\n";
        }
        return;
    }
};
```

Functions.cpp file

```
#include "Header.h"

// reads string data from a file into a vector of strings passed by reference
// each line from the file is a string in the resulting vector
void readGeneral(const std::string& filename, std::vector<std::string>& vec) {
    // variables needed
    std::string line;

    // opening filestream
    std::fstream file_in(filename, std::ios_base::in);
    // checking if file opened correctly
    if (file_in.is_open()) {
        // read all values in file
        while (std::getline(file_in, line)) {
            vec.push_back(line);
        }
        // close the file
        file_in.close();
        return;
    }
    // error handling if file was not opened correctly
    else {
        throw "Error Opening File in readCoords2D\n";
    }
}

// reads string data from a file into a MatrixXd and returns it
// converts any non-numerical data into its ASCII equivalent value
myMatrix read2Mat(const std::string& filename, unsigned int mode) {

    // if mode is set to 0, we are reading information from a matrix with no ids
    if (mode == 0) {
        // read data from file into vector
        std::vector<std::string> vec;
        readGeneral(filename, vec);

        // read data from vector into MatrixXd
        // rows - size of vec
        // cols - # of words in the first string of vector vec
        myMatrix mat(vec.size(), countWords(vec[0]));
        std::string word;
        unsigned int j = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            j = 0;
            std::stringstream stream(vec[i]);
            while (stream >> word) {
                if (is_number(word)) {
                    mat(i, j) = stod(word);
                }
                else {
                    throw "Error in read2Mat function mode 0. A value in the file is not of numerical type";
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return mat;
    }

    // if mode is set to 1, we are reading information from a matrix where the first column is a column of ids
    else if (mode == 1) {
        // read data from file into vector
        std::vector<std::string> vec;
        readGeneral(filename, vec);

        // read data from vector into MatrixXd
        // rows - size of vec
        // cols - # of words in the first string of vector vec
        myMatrix mat(vec.size(), countWords(vec[0]) - 1, 1);
        std::string word;
        unsigned int j = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            j = 0;
            std::stringstream stream(vec[i]);
            while (stream >> word) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    mat.ref0(i) = word;
                }
                else if (j != 0 && is_number(word)) {
                    mat(i, j - 1) = stod(word);
                }
                else {
                    throw "Error in read2Mat function mode 1. A value not in the first column is of string type";
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return mat;
    }

    // if mode is set to 1, we are reading information from a matrix where the first column is a column of ids
    else if (mode == 2) {
        // read data from file into vector
        std::vector<std::string> vec;
        readGeneral(filename, vec);

        // read data from vector into MatrixXd
        // rows - size of vec
        // cols - # of words in the first string of vector vec
        myMatrix mat(vec.size(), countWords(vec[0]) - 2, 1);
        std::string word;
        unsigned int j = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            j = 0;
            std::stringstream stream(vec[i]);
            while (stream >> word) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    mat.ref0(i) = word;
                }
                else if (j == 1) {
                    mat.ref1(i) = word;
                }
                else if (j != 0 && is_number(word)) {
                    mat(i, j - 1) = stod(word);
                }
                else {
                    throw "Error in read2Mat function mode 1. A value not in the first column is of string type";
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return mat;
    }
}

// checks if a string is a valid double
// (fails if there is a single character that is not 0-9, ., or +-) 
// (passes if there is whitespace at the front, but fails if it is at the end)
bool is_number(const std::string& str) {
    char* end = nullptr;
    double val = strtod(str.data(), &end);
    return end != str.c_str() && *end == '\0' && val != HUGE_VAL;
}

// counts how many words there are in a string
unsigned int countWords(const std::string& str) {
    std::stringstream stream(str);
    std::string word;
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    while (stream >> word) {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

// returns the value at row i and column j in "MatrixXd values" by using the parenthesis operator
// overloaded for normal and const objects
double& myMatrix::operator()(const unsigned int& i, const unsigned int& j) {
    return values(i, j);
}
double myMatrix::operator()(const unsigned int& i, const unsigned int& j) const {
    return values(i, j);
}
```

Comment: please post the complete error message. And please read about [mcve], most of your code is not necessary to reproduce the error

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/5vrTfxK19. However, I had to rearrange the code a little. In the header you declare `myMatrix read2Mat(const std::string& filename, unsigned int mode);` before `myMatrix` is declared. After removing the code in the methods, that was the only error I got

Comment: Sorry for posting such a long question. I thought it would be helpful to post my entire files, didn't know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I was trying to edit my answer to get the minimal reproducible example and just like you pointed out, my mistake was that I was using `myMatrix` before it was declared just. Thanks for all your help!